# Cubic bezier for easing?

Tags: xna, c#, beziers, easing

I would like to find out what Y is if X is a certain number from a cubic bezier curve to make a custom easing function, like it's done on this site: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Does anyone know a formula or a function to find Y if X is something of a cubic-bezier? (Coding in C#/XNA)

Comment: There are several correct values for y in a generic cubic bezier.

Comment: The answer is now updated with an implementation.

Comment: Is it necessary that the curve be a Bezier specifically, or will any function that smoothly maps the range [0,1] onto a curve beginning at 0 and ending at 1 with controllable tangents suffice? If the latter is okay, there are options for computing y as a function of x directly, rather than via an intermediate parameter t. Cubic Hermite is one example, although it's not as expressive as a Bezier (can't express vertical tangents, but it can mimic any of the standard easing types listed along the bottom of the example link), it's simpler and faster than searching for the right t.

Answer (score 4):

Lets look at two approaches:

1. Binary search - assuming the Bezier is set with values where there is one `Y` for each `X`, meaning that there is an injective function that receives an `X` and returns a `Y` then you can search for the correct `t` value that will return the `x,y` pair you are looking for.
2. Precomputation: Computing 1000 values for `t` between in the range `[0 1]` should only take an instant and you can place the results in 200 buckets. Afterwards, you could easily get a tiny set of relevant `x,y` pairs by simply picking the relevant bucket from the array.

Lets explore this in more depth (this is the formula):

[image: bezier formula]

To do a binary search, we'll assume that you create a specialized function `h(t)` that commputes the `x` value for a given `t` and returns it.

We are looking for the `y` value where `x=a` for some `a` so we need to find the correct `t` such that `h(t)` (nearly) equals `x`.

```
h(t) : return (1 - t)^3 * x0 + 3(1 - t)^2t * x1 + 3(1 - t)t^2 * x2 + t^3 * x3;

//Util
sign(z) : (z >= 0)? 1 : -1;
abs(z) : z * sign(z);

//binary search :
lookup(a) : 
  t = 0.5;
  step = 0.5;
  precision = 0.0001;
  While(abs(h(t) - a) > precision) :
    step /= 2.0;
    t += sign(a - h(t)) * step;
```

I did not check the code for faults so you"re welcome to look for errors.

Other method:

Calculate the `Y` and `X` values for a 1000 values of `t` (in advance). Put the results into buckets in an array of length `N`. `x` is between `[0 1]` so place all results between `M/N` and `(M + 1)/N` in the list in index M in the bucket array. You can later use a (fast) lookup to find the `x,y` pair you want (by radix/range). Binary search (and Newton Raphson) are you friends when you want to quickly answer complex mathematical questions with the use of a computer. You can still use the binary search to increase precision after the look up by searching between the two closest values.

A quick recap: you store the `x,y` pairs in **linked-lists** within an **array of [buckets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)** by creating lists of `x,y` pairs where the values of `x`(s) that are between `[m/n (m+1)/n]` are all stored in the `m`th index (i.e. in `listarray[m]`).

Comment: If you need an clarification, feel welcome

Comment: A binary search is probably overkill for tweening. A numerically-precalculated 1D lookup table with fixed spacing on the X axis is probably a better approach. (Not sure how a hash is applicable here.)

Comment: Actually, if you're willing to do a binary search, and you can figure out if the curve is a [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) (possibly numerically or by constraining the inputs), then you don't even need the lookup table. You can do a binary search on `B(t).X` itself, and save yourself the lookup table (it's probably faster).

Comment: What you described as a 1D lookup table is what I described as a hash in my answer. ;) I mean the hash function is simply one that will provide the set of values between m/n and (m+1)/n when you look for some fraction representing x between 0 and 1. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AndrewRussell Again, doing a binary search on the function (using t) is also the second part of the answer.

Comment: Yep - just understood what you meant just as you commented. That's a [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), not a hash table. Still - probably not the most efficient choice for something like tweening.

Comment: I think that does not qualify as bucket sort because I am not continuing with finer granularity in order to produce a sorted array but I find terminology is often ambiguous. I heard both the term hash used for this and some O(N) sorting terms like bean sorting used to describe this. If you decide to edit the answer I'll welcome it.

Comment: Certainly. I just noticed you actually had actually suggested binary search on the equation itself all along. I took the liberty of bolding that - because it's buried in all the stuff about lookups - and I feel that it is by far the better solution (for any solution that is not `O(1)`).

Comment: (The thing about a hash table is it, you know, involves a hash function ;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that `floor(p.x * N)` isn't a generally sought after hash function for x values between 0 and 1 but it can be considered a useful hash function when you are inserting uniformly distributed values and are interested in their order.

Comment: Would somebody be kind enough to show me this method in an example, as I am rather new to coding in general

Comment: First please read about implementing Binary Search. There is a lot of data about it online. If you still can't figure it out, feel welcome to ask a question about binary search on Stack. I'll add implementation later today.